# SASS/SCSS Background-image loop with nth-child

Tags: loops, sass, background-image

I'm creating a portfolio section of my static website and I'd like a neat way of assigning background-image url:s without adding any classnames (image image-1, image image-2 etc.) or style tags in HTML, **but rather use only scss with nth-child, if possible**...

Because the image divs are nested I have some problems assigning background-images using nth-child. I've created a JSFiddle to reproduce the problem (**the image divs are nested inside rows**).

My image files are named like in the fiddle (image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg etc.).

The fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/szmvfo4o/

The loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {

  .row:nth-child(#{$i}) {

    .image:first-child {
      background-image: url(image-#{$i}.jpg);
    } 

    .image:last-child {
      background-image: url(image-#{$i+1}.jpg);
    } 

  }

}
```

Full SCSS:

```
.item {

  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.inner {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.image {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff;
  //background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/-sQ4FsomXEs/800x600);
  background-image: url(image-1.jpg);

}

@for $i from 1 through 3 {

  .row:nth-child(#{$i}) {

    .image:first-child {
      background-image: url(image-#{$i}.jpg);
    } 

    .image:last-child {
      background-image: url(image-#{$i+1}.jpg);
    } 

  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong.

Please use below code.

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {

  .row:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    .item:first-child {
      .image {
        background-image: url(image-#{$i}.jpg);
      } 
    }
    .item:last-child {
      .image {
        background-image: url(image-#{$i+1}.jpg);
      } 
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could as well consider using flexbox. Wrap everything in container div

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Get rid of row divs, without the need of rows, the loop would look like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {

    .item:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      .inner {
        .image {
          background-image: url(image-#{$i}.jpg);
          }
      }
    } 
}
```

see the rest of the code in the Fiddle here >> https://jsfiddle.net/2f0hgfh8/

In previous solution, the loop didn't work correctly, because on every row ($i) it counted image $i and $i+1. In result it looked like this:

```
image1 image2
image2 image3
image3 image4
image4 image5
```